# How to iterate over rows of a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I want to iterate over rows of a dataset (row by row) and get value of a certain column, how to achieve this ?
I tried with :

```
oldDF.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> System.out.println(row));
```

Is it the right way ? else how to achieve it and how to access the value of a column of a row ?

Thanks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to output the value of a specific column, you can actually use a `select` query for this particular column and just show the results on the console like that:

```
oldDF.select("_2").show() // show the 2nd column's values of oldDF
```

In case you want to have the elements of this column in an `Array` of type `Rows`, you can swap the `show()` method with [collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect--) or [collectAsList()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collectAsList--) like this:

```
oldDF.select("_2").collect() // store the 2nd column's values of oldDF
```